# Iteration through two Pandas Dataframes + create new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, matching

I am new to using Pandas and I am trying to iterate through two columns from different Dataframes and if both columns have the same word, to append "yes" to another column. If not, append the word "no".

This is what I have:

```
    for row in df1.iterrows():
     for word in df2.iterrows():
       if df1['word1'] == df2['word2']:
         df1.column1.append('Yes') #I just want to have two columns in binary form, if one is yes the other must be no
         df2.column2.append('No')

       else:
         df1.column1.append('No')
         df2.column2.append('Yes')
```

I Have now:

```
      column1      column2  column3   
       apple        None    None
       orange       None    None
       banana       None    None
       tomato       None    None
       sugar        None    None
       grapes       None    None
       fig          None    None
```

I want:

```
      column1      column2  column3   
       apple           Yes       No
       orange          No        No
       banana          No        No
       tomato          No        No
       sugar           No        Yes
       grapes          No        Yes
       figs            No        Yes


    Sample of words from df1: apple, orange, pear
    Sample of words from df2: yellow, orange, green
```

I get this error:
**Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects**

Note: The words in df2 are 2500 than the words in df1 are 500.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you share an example of your desired output please? Also, can you share a sample of your df1 and df2 so we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just added some edits. I hope I made it clearer now.

Comment: thank you for sharing the example. I dont understand the logic why column1=b will result in column 2 & 3 = No while the similar value in column1=a resulted in Yes and No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you want to fill:

- *df1.column1* with:

  - *Yes* - if *word1* from this row occurs in *df2.word1* (in any row),
  - *No* - otherwise,
- *df2.column2* with:

  - *Yes* - if *word2* from this row occurs in *df1.word2* (in any row),
  - *No* - otherwise.

To do it, you can run:

```
df1['column1'] = np.where(df1.word1.isin(df2.word2), 'Yes', 'No')
df2['column2'] = np.where(df2.word2.isin(df1.word1), 'Yes', 'No')
```

To test my code I used the following DataFrames:

```
df1:                 df2:
        word1                word2
0       apple        0      yellow
1      orange        1      orange
2        pear        2       green
3  strawberry        3  strawberry
                     4        plum
```

The result of my code is:

```
df1:                       df2:
        word1 column1              word2 column2
0       apple      No      0      yellow      No
1      orange     Yes      1      orange     Yes
2        pear      No      2       green      No
3  strawberry     Yes      3  strawberry     Yes
                           4        plum      No
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a better idea to get `set` of words from both columns and then do lookup. It would be way faster as well. Something like this:

```
words_df1 = set(df1['word1'].tolist())
words_df2 = set(df2['word2'].tolist())
```

Then do

```
df1['has_word2'] = df1['word1'].isin(words_df2)
df2['has_word1'] = df2['word2'].isin(words_df1)
```